# Access Files in a Remote Server using SQL Server Job

Tags: sql-server

I need to access some XML files in a different server in the network using a SQL script.

I managed to develop the following Stored Procedure and it is working when it executed through EXEC Command. but when I add it to a SQL Server Job it does not work.

```
USE [New_Graphic_DB_ver1]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[USP_DFS_XML_IMPORT]    Script Date: 9/22/2022 4:23:28 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_DFS_XML_IMPORT]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

-----------Connecting to the Network Drive------------------
EXECUTE SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
--GO

EXECUTE SP_CONFIGURE 'xp_cmdshell', '1'
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
--GO
EXECUTE SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 0
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'net use   s:   \\200.0.0.70\PlateReport\test   test  /user:test /y '

------------------Obtaining the files-----------------------

DECLARE @Path nvarchar(500) = 's:\'
--Change the path 
DECLARE @FindFile TABLE  (FileNames nvarchar(500)  ,depth int  ,isFile int) 
INSERT INTO @FindFile EXEC xp_DirTree @Path,1,1
--SELECT FileNames from @FindFile where isFile=1

DECLARE @i INT = 0;
DECLARE  @count INT = 0;
DECLARE @FileNames nvarchar(500)='DUM'
DECLARE @Fn nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @F nvarchar(200)
SELECT @count=  Count(*) FROM @FindFile

WHILE @i <= @count-1
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
            SELECT @f=FileNames FROM @FindFile
            ORDER BY FileNames
            OFFSET @i ROWS
            FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY  

        set @fn=concat(@path, @f)

        DECLARE @InsertSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=NULL
        SET @InsertSQL= 'INSERT INTO dbo.DFS_XML_IMPORT(Job_Name, Job_Date, Plate_Name,Plate_Width,Plate_Height,TotalSize,Waste)
        SELECT
           MY_XML.Job.query(''JobName'').value(''.'', ''nvarchar(150)''),
           MY_XML.Job.query(''Date'').value(''.'', ''datetime''),
           MY_XML1.Plate.query(''PlateName'').value(''.'', ''nvarchar(150)''),
           MY_XML1.Plate.query(''PlateWidth'').value(''.'', ''numeric(18, 5)''),
           MY_XML1.Plate.query(''PlateHeight'').value(''.'', ''numeric(18, 5)''),
           MY_XML1.Plate.query(''TotalSize'').value(''.'', ''numeric(18, 5)''),
           MY_XML1.Plate.query(''Waste'').value(''.'', ''numeric(18, 5)'')
        FROM (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
              FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '''+ @fn +''' , SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
              CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes(''Jobinformation/JOB'') AS MY_XML (Job)
              CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes(''Jobinformation/Plate'') AS MY_XML1 (Plate)'

            SET @i = @i + 1;

        Print @InsertSQL
        EXEC(@InsertSQL)

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
      SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_MESSAGE();

    Print ERROR_NUMBER();
    Print ERROR_MESSAGE();

    END CATCH;
END

---------------Disconnecting from the Network Drive ---------------------------
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'net use s: /delete /y'

EXECUTE SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
--GO
EXECUTE SP_CONFIGURE 'xp_cmdshell', '0'
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
--GO
EXECUTE SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 0
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE


    -- Insert statements for procedure here
--  SELECT <@Param1, sysname, @p1>, <@Param2, sysname, @p2>
END
```

When I check history log of the Job, I found the following error

[SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  Cannot bulk load because the file "s:\694-plate-170-09-22-PF.xml" could not be opened.
Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.)

Kindly help me to rectify this issue.

Comment: There are many problems with what has been presented, including usage of `xp_dirtree` which is on the Microsoft's recommended security settings as one of the extended procedures that should be deleted on an instance ... since SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Highly recommend replacing all of that with an external process, even a PowerShell script (which, coincidentally, can also be scheduled from a SQL Agent job), to import and shred the data files.

Comment: Noted with thanks.   Kindly send me a sample code